# How to make my menuItems appear on the Frame

Tags: java, swing, menu, jmenuitem

When i run this code the menuItems do not appear. I call this Menu method in my main class. The JFrame does display a white menubar but there are no menuItems and no dropdowns. Any advice on how I could fix this.

```
public void createScreen() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("SpreadSheets");
    this.setSize(w, h);

}

public void resizerValue() {
    w = this.getWidth();
    h = this.getHeight();

}

public void Menu() {

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    // creates bar
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");

    // makes the menu
    JMenuItem mnuNew = new JMenuItem(ACTION_NEW);
    JMenuItem mnuLoad = new JMenuItem(ACTION_LOAD);
    JMenuItem mnuSave = new JMenuItem(ACTION_SAVE);


    // creates the menuItems
    mnuNew.setActionCommand(ACTION_NEW);
    mnuLoad.setActionCommand(ACTION_LOAD);
    mnuSave.setActionCommand(ACTION_SAVE);

    // sets the items commands in the ActionCommand
    mnuNew.addActionListener(this);
    mnuLoad.addActionListener(this);
    mnuSave.addActionListener(this);



    // adds the functions to the action Listener
    menu.add(mnuNew);
    menu.add(mnuSave);
    menu.add(mnuLoad);


    menuBar.add(menu);


    // adds them to menu
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    // adds this menu to the bar

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Start with the working examples from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). The demos code from the tutorial will also show you how to better structure your code (ie. you should not be extending JFrame).